# For every non-closed set, there is a continuous function that has no continuous extension

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

I have a question. We know that "if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed set, then every continuous function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous extension from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$".

But I now I have to prove "if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a non-closed set, then there is a continuous function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ which has no continuous extension from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$". This means when we omit the assumption about closedness of $A$, the theorem does not hold.

But how can we prove for every non-closed set $A$?

I find a similar question that we can prove by the contrapositive: [If every continuous function on a set can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ then the set is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3745435)

But my question is "Is there any way to prove directly?"

Please give me some hints. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to the question that you have linked also answers yours.

Comment: Yes, they have linked. But all I want is to provide a different approach to it.

Comment: The answer to the other question is the same as the answer that you have accepted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theree is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ converging to a point $a$ which is not in $A$. $f(x)=\frac 1 {x-a}$ defines a continuous function on $A$ which does not extend to any continuous function on $\mathbb  R$ since $|f(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to a$.